# Size of 802.11 packet

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap, wifi

Given the below declaration for pcap callback:

```
void my_callback(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
```

How to ascertain the total number of bytes present in the packet? I need that value so that I can pass it to crc32() function.

Comment: Maybe the `const struct pcap_pkthdr *header` has the information you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [this reference](http://www.ferrisxu.com/WinPcap/html/structpcap__pkthdr.html) the information about the size of the packet is in the `pcap_pkthdr`'s structure

Answer (score 0):

The information is in the `pcap_pkthdr` variable.

Given your callback, the full packet size is given by

```
header->len
```

and the captured packet size (which might be smaller if you've set a snaplen that happens to be smaller than actual packet size) is given by

```
header->caplen
```